# Delete records from huge table which are not exists in large subset from another table

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, bigdata

Below is ma method (Symfony, Doctrine) to removing etities where its ids are not present in other table which contains together list of ids from several different types. (exactly 6, but it is important only to understand the structure of system)

And everything works perfect unless the method is called with parameter of entity which contains about 300000 records and the helper table ('oId') has similar amount of records. (so the method should remove only several records I explain) When earlier all works (a records count of to tables below the 50000), here I encounter the problem from database:

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction

This error never appear with the previous entities.
I don't know what is the problem because count of records is only ten times bigger so when those queries are executed through several seconds, why I can't see result after eg. 20 s.?
What is behind the scene, that such error is thrown?

I even rebuild my method to do the task in loop as it was said in some answers about how to delete huge amount of records from table. Also I decreased limit to 1000 records and everything run ok, except when it start doing it with the entity described earlier.

Here is the whole method.

Only one more little explanation. Don't be afraid of sql injection. The $typeId and $borderId cames from database not from the user.

```
/**
 * Deletes records from given entity which are not exists in imported csv file.
 *
 * @param string $entity
 * @param integer $typeId
 * @param int $borderId Additional condition. Eg. 5 means, none of entities below id of value 5 will be delted (id < 5)
 */
public function removeNonExistent($entity, $typeId, $borderId = null)
{
    $subQueryQb = $this->repository->createQueryBuilder('oId');
    $subQueryQb->select('oId.originalId')
        ->andWhere('oId.type = '.$typeId)
        //->andWhere('oId.originalId = e.originalId')
        //Uncomment to have subquery of EXIST rather the IN()
    ;

    $qb = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb->select('min(e.id) as minId, max(e.id) as maxId, count(e.id) as countId');
    $qb->from($entity, 'e');
    $tableData = $qb->getQuery()->getArrayResult();

    $queries = 0;
    $limit = 1000;
    $id = $tableData[0]['minId'];
    while ($id < $tableData[0]['maxId']) {

        $deleteQb = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();
        $deleteQb->delete()
            ->from($entity, 'e')
            ->andWhere('e.id BETWEEN '.$id.' AND '.($id + $limit - 1))
            ->andWhere($deleteQb->expr()->notIn('e.originalId', $subQueryQb→getDQL())) //Comment to use subquery as EXIST rather than IN()
            //->andWhere($deleteQb->expr()->not($deleteQb->expr()->exists($subQueryQb->getDQL())))
         //Uncomment to use subquery as EXIST rather than IN()  
        ;
        if ($borderId !== null) {
            $deleteQb->andWhere('e.id > '.$borderId);
        }

        $qResult = $deleteQb->getQuery()->getResult();
        $this->em->flush($entity);
        $queries++;
        echo $queries.'# delete query executed. Rows deleted: '.$qResult."\n";
        $id += $limit;

        if ($tableData[0]['countId'] < $limit) {
            break;
        }
    }

    echo $queries.' delete queries executed.'."\n";
}
```

Anyone can help? I will be glad for any kind of any clue.

Comment: use sleeping between iterations

Comment: Could it be so easy? Now I cannot check but as soon as I can, I will check it. I believe that is it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show us the resulting SQL.  Do not use `IN ( SELECT ... )` it is likely to be slower than `LEFT JOIN`.  Use `autocommit`, not one big transaction.

Comment: @mcklayin I changed it and added sleep(1) but with changed limit to 31000 I don't know why i got 27 queries if limit was 31000. (in table are about 321000 records) Another thing strange is that at the first run of script after login I got into 27# query and script suspended and never continued again. In second run it suspended and rise above error at the beginning of execution. Even none of lines like d# delete query... appeared.

Comment: @RickJames It is doctrine and it generates query so in the code all needed to construct the query is given I think. According to LEFT JOIN I rather don't know how it should look like so could you give mi any sample? According to autocommit, as is written in doctrine docs _By default a connection runs in auto-commit mode which means that it is non-transactional unless you start a transaction explicitly via beginTransaction()_ I changed nothing i that behaviour. And info from previous my comment is also valid to this comment. Thanks for any help!

Comment: @mcklayin it really stops at the beginning because first and second id is respectively 1 and 3 and third in order is 837704 so this solve this strange behaviour (27*31000=837000). It also means that problem of suspending of the script is not solved. I only can explain why this gap of ids exists. It is because I constantly remove whole records except those two first in new attempt of import. But I do this by phpMyAdmin. I should add that the problem of timeout also appear in phpMyAdmin when I execute query written by hand according to this which is coded in queryBuilder in given code.

Comment: Running a query in "auto-commit mode" means that each statement is an implicit transaction.  That is, it could timeout.  When making recommendations in this area, I tend to say "1000 rows at a time".  Try that.  And you could probably decrease the sleep to `usleep(100000)`.

Comment: If there were error messages, please provide them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing which I discovered is the last line of this query

```
DELETE FROM table
WHERE id NOT IN (
        SELECT a.original_id 
        FROM table_ids a
        WHERE a.type = 6           
) 
AND id > 3
```

If the query has this form (without last line – we are still talking about MySQL5.6)

```
DELETE FROM table
WHERE id NOT IN (
        SELECT a.original_id 
        FROM table_ids a
        WHERE a.type = 6           
) 
– (without last this line)
```

The query with count of ids equal to about 300 thousands with this line excluded all executes very quickly (about several seconds) but if I add the line  AND id > 3 everything slow down to even stopping.
So this is the solution but I MUST have this condition!

Well now it comes solution number two:

```
   /**
    * Deletes records from given entity which are not exists in imported csv file.
    *
    * @param string $entity
    * @param integer $typeId
    * @param int $borderId Additional condition. Eg. 5 means, none of entities below id of value 5 will be delted (id < 5)
    */
    public function removeNonExistent($entity, $typeId, $borderId = null)
    {
        $metaData = $this->em->getClassMetadata($entity);
        $mainMetaData = $this->em->getClassMetadata($this->class);

        $connection = $this->em->getConnection();

        $connection->query('BEGIN;');

        $connection->query('CREATE TABLE '.$metaData->getTableName().'_copy LIKE '.$metaData->getTableName().';');

        $connection->query('INSERT INTO '.$metaData->getTableName().'_copy
            SELECT *
            FROM '.$metaData->getTableName().'
            WHERE '.$metaData->getTableName().'.'.$metaData->getColumnName('originalId').' IN (
                SELECT '.$mainMetaData->getColumnName('originalId').' FROM '.$mainMetaData->getTableName().' WHERE '.$mainMetaData->getColumnName('type').' = '.$typeId.'
            )
             ;');

        if ($borderId !== null) {
            $connection->query('INSERT INTO '.$metaData->getTableName().'_copy
                SELECT *
                FROM '.$metaData->getTableName().'
                WHERE '.$metaData->getTableName().'.'.$metaData->getColumnName('id').' <= '.$borderId.';');
        }

        $connection->query('RENAME TABLE '.$metaData->getTableName().' TO '.$metaData->getTableName().'_old, '.$metaData->getTableName().'_copy TO '.$metaData->getTableName().';');

        $connection->query('
            ALTER TABLE '.$metaData->getTableName().' DISABLE KEYS;
            SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
            SET UNIQUE_CHECKS = 0;
            SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
        ;');
        $connection->query('DROP TABLE '.$metaData->getTableName().'_old;');
        $connection->query('
            SET UNIQUE_CHECKS = 1;
            SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
            ALTER TABLE '.$metaData->getTableName().' ENABLE KEYS;
        ;');

        $connection->query('COMMIT;');
    }
```

Simply and shortly:
We copy data to the new tmp table then we change names and all return the previous order.

And now it works.
Only one disadvantage is that I have to rebuild schema of database while the foreign keys are not added.

I only wonder why this simple line of one more condition
AND id > 3
makes the query unable to finish…

And in the end one clearification:
When I first executed the script from the question I did't want to wait so long when the query had been executed so I entered ^C. Every next time the error of timeout appeared. Only very first time there was no error as well as no effect and what is more end.

So that it is.